How do scholars interpret Psalm 36:5 from the perspective of units of physical measurement Vs literary analogy?
We read in Psalm 36:5 (AKJV):

Thy mercy, O Lord, is in the heavens;
and thy faithfulness reacheth unto the clouds.

Generally, people especially those  residing on hills know that clouds move at  a lower  height as compared to the sky  even if a boundary was   assumed for the latter in ancient times. Did the writer of Psalms intend to say that the mercy of the Lord is greater than his faithfulness to the promises he had made to his people ?  How do scholars interpret Psalm 36:5 from the perspective of units of physical measurement Vs literary analogy ?

If I say to Albert Einstein: “Your wisdom shines like the sun ☀️ and your discoveries - like the stars ✨ of the firmament!”, it does not mean that the discoveries, that are manifestations of the wisdom, are less valuable than the wisdom, just because the sun shines more intensely than stars.
Similarly, the faithfulness of God is in no manner of a lesser gravity than the mercy of God, just because ☁️ are lover than the heavens’  remotest and highest parts.

Thanks, Levan. My take is this : God promised Israel many favours for obedience to the Commandments. Israel miserably failed, but God in his infinite mercy, granted them the favours. Thus, his mercy transcended his faithfulness.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan His faithfulness then is not at all changed, but Israel fell short of it. If the sun promises me to give me its tan but I do not expose myself to the sun’s rays, problem is in me, not in sun’s faithfulness to its promise.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Sorry, I could not understand initially your response. That divine mercy eclipses His justice, is said in Bible clearly, also by James in New Testament. Has the clouds and heavens metaphor to do anything with this hierarchical distinction, I doubt, but in any case it is a theologically a very plausible and beautiful explanation, even if objectively not precise, of which I cannot be 100% sure.

Thanks, Levan. Hope you develop your thoughts into a comprehensive answer.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Actually, as St. Augustine says, whatever theologically sound interpretation may be extracted from Bible, let it be, even if philologically-objectively it is implausible!

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Moreover, St Augustine says that Holy Spirit predicted and inspired such interpretations, and yours is truly very spiritual and beautiful interpretation!

Thanks, Levan. I stand enlightened.

"assuredly the Holy Spirit, who through him (a prophet) spoke these words, foresaw that this interpretation would occur to the reader, nay, made provision that it should occur to him, seeing that it too is founded on truth. For what more liberal and more fruitful provision could God have made in regard to the Sacred Scriptures than that the same words might be understood in several senses, all of which are sanctioned by the concurring testimony of other passages equally divine?" - St Augustine "De doctrina christiana" B.III, ch. 3.
